# Accumulated discrete solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Consider the two equations
$$
\text{eq 1: }n=km
$$
$$\text{eq 2: }n=(k-1)m+1$$
for $n,m,k\in\mathbb{N}$. For $N$ such that $n\in [1,N]$, is it always true that the first equation has more accumulated solutions than the second (except at $N=1$)? That seems to be the case, the difference between the number of accumulated solutions is always non-negative (up to $N=1000$), as seen here

[image]

How could one prove that? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations are nearly identical.  The second can be rewritten as $$n-1=(k-1)m$$ after all. The only difference arises at the "boundary" (solutions where $k$ or $n$ are at extremes).

Note that, if $(n,m,k)$ satisfies the second equation, $(n+1,m,k+1)$ satisfies the first (unless $n=N$). Plus the first has $N$  solutions of the form $(n,n,1)$ which do not arise from a solution to the second.

So the only issue is, how many solutions to the second equation are there for which $n=N$?  But of course there are fewer than $N$ since you only count the divisors of $N-1$.